# Write new text to a textbox when clicking a button?

Tags: c#, forms, onclick, textbox

So I am making a simple stopwatch using the Windows Forms and I have a functioning stopwatch that I have created. 
I want to write the current time on the watch to a textbox with the number/place in the race before it.

Design:

Stopwatch

Start Stop Finish

Textbox

So whenever I press "Finish" I want the textbox to display the number that this is/placement as well as the time at finish.
So something like:

1. 2:15.4
2. 2:18.5
3. 2:24.5

etc.

Is this possible to do for someone who does only have a basic understanding of C#?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it will be smth like this:

```
NameOfYourTextBox.Text = "some string here";
```

Comment: That won't work since it will just overwrite the content in the box each time you click the button.

Comment: Ok, my answer was "very general", and sure we can manipulate with "some string here"...